# importerror: cannot import name 'dump' from 'dump' (~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dump/__init__.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The line from dump import dump gives the error given in the title.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# make new dump file by combining snapshots from multiple NEB replica dumps
# Syntax: neb_combine.py -switch arg(s) -switch arg(s) ...
#         -o outfile = new dump file
#            each snapshot has NEB atoms from all replicas
#         -r dump1 dump2 ... = replica dump files of NEB atoms
#            can be in any order
#         -b dumpfile = background atoms (optional)
#            first snapshot in this file used as static non-NEB atoms

import sys,os
path = os.environ["LAMMPS_PYTHON_TOOLS"]
sys.path.append(path)
from dump import dump
```

Comment: Have you... installed that library? could you please share your code?

Comment: Yes, I have done 'pip3 install dump'.

Comment: I have this line 'from dump import dump' which gives me error

Comment: Please try to provide de code of your error and all details to reproduce. [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The full code can be found in the folder: ~/lammps-stable/lammps-23Jun2022/tools/python if you install LAMMPS sotware

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question in the MATSCI community and found the answer. Full discussion here.

https://matsci.org/t/using-python-with-lammps-i-am-not-able-to-import-a-module/44096

Apparently, the error was due to the installed dump library in the local python package installation.